# ERROR: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' ngrx async pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable, ngrx

My main app component dispatches an action that gets the data from the API and loads it into the store in property `config`, then when the page loads, my form component selects config from the store, and binds it to the child component that then displays it with the `async pipe`. Other posts I looked at said the problem is that the value is not an observable, but I know mine is, because I have subscribed to it, and can log the array of objects. I just can't get it to go through the async pipe.

the data object from config is an array of satOptions `SatOption[]`

```
export interface SatOption {
    satelliteId: number;
    satelliteName: string;
    channels: Channel[];
}
```

parent ngOnInit

```
this.config$ = this.store.select((state:any) => state.appReducer.config)
this.config$.subscribe(slice => console.log(slice))
```

child template

```
<select [formControl]="satControl">
    <option
        class="hide-select"
        value="default"
        disabled
    >
        pick a satellite
    </option>
    <option
        *ngFor="let sat of (config$ | async)"
        [value]="sat.channels"
        [attr.set]="sat"
    >
        {{ sat.satelliteName }}
    </option>
</select>
```

my console.log:

```
Array(3) [ {…}, {…}, {…} ]
```

the attr.set binding shows `[object Object]`

I'm really at a loss, I have tried subscribing and re-assigning and get the same result. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the full code, I would assume that you're passing an array (and not an Observable array) to your child template, this would mean you don't need to use the `async` pipe anymore.

Parent:

```
<my-child [items]="items | async"></my-child>
```

Child:

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items">{{ item.name }}</li>
```

Comment: Isn't a call from the store always asynchronous? I tried without the pipe and the error goes away, but the data attr still displays [object Object]

Comment: Yea, if you select from the store it's always an Observable. The data attr can't display a javascript object, hence [Object object]. If you really want to display to object you'll have to JSON.stringify it.

Comment: It's just very strange, I have another project that streams data from the store just like this and it works great. And I have seen many others do it too. Is it because I dispatch the action in app, and then select the data at a later time from another component? The thing is, it is of type observable<array{myobject}>, I have confirmed that much.

Comment: So, can you explain in your answer why having the binding on the child selector with | async worked, but not in the child html template?

Comment: How did you do it before? Did you use the async pipe in both of the components? Because if you would only do it once it works, it doesn't matter if you do it in the parent or in the child component. I would suggest to keep your child component as simple as possible, this means you get your items as an array instead of an observable.

Comment: in my other working project, it was in my child ngfor, "let item of (object | async)?.itemList" and it worked. but in the OP i had the same thing, didnt work until I changed it to <my-child [items]="items | async"> and passed the array from the start. I don't understand